# Target only the span of current row jQuery

Tags: jquery

How could I target the span only of the current row?Did some research `closest` might work but I can't some under stand its usage for table.

```
   var spanID = $(this).closest('tr').next().find('span').attr("[name='wpc_subtotal']");
    spanID.text(sum);
```

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rdanalasa/pyqhh45p/).

Comment: How do you know which row is "current"?

Comment: @nnnnnn updated my question .

Comment: If `this` is an element within the current row then your use of `.next()` is looking in the row after that. Use `$(this).closest('tr').find('span')...`

Comment: @nnnnnn `var spanID = $(this).closest('tr').find('span').attr("[name='wpc_subtotal']");
        spanID.text(sum);`

Comment: @nnnnnn something like this?It's currently not working.Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Why are you using `.attr()`? That method returns the string value of the specified attribute, it doesn't select an element. If you're trying to set the `.text()` value then don't use `.attr()` at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154093/discussion-between-rai-nalasa-and-nnnnnn).

Comment: What nnnnnn is telling you is to use either `var spanID = $(this).closest('tr').find('span[name="wpc_subtotal‌​"]'); spanID.text(sum);` or `var spanID = $(this).closest('tr').find('span'); spanID.text(sum);`. `.attr()` will return the value of the attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove next from your code () as it refer to the next tr which has value of zero because you don't change it you refer other element than your target.

```
 var spanID = $(this).closest('tr').find('span').attr("[name='wpc_subtotal']");
```

Comment: I did that on my fiddle.I still can't figure out where I got wrong.

Comment: I try it in this way and it work may be you have to enclose click event with $(document).ready